# How do I install Z.SH to my Linux?

Tags: linux, bashrc

I want to install [Z](https://github.com/rupa/z/) to my Linux:

Here's the installation notes:

```
# INSTALL:
#   * put something like this in your .bashrc:
#     . /path/to/z.sh
#   * put something like this in your .zshrc:
#     . /path/to/z.sh
#     function precmd () {
#       z --add "$(pwd -P)"
#     }
#   * cd around for a while to build up the db
#   * PROFIT!!
```

The problem is I'm a newbie in Linux, please give me an easy to understand guide.. This installation notes are just too hard to understand..

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+.bashrc

Comment: thats not helpful at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal.

1. Go to `/home/your-linux-username`
2. Type this: `gedit .bashrc`
3. At the end of `.bashrc`, paste this:

   ```
   ./path/to/downloaded/file/z.sh

   function precmd () {

        z --add "$(pwd -P)"

   }
   ```
4. You are done.

Now, close restart your terminal, fire some cd commands, like: cd /home/id

then `z dir-name` will work.